# Creating a detached process in Rust on Windows with a shared secret

Tags: winapi, rust

I've got a server that generates a secret key used for encryption and authentication when it begins listening. It shares this key over stdout with the expectation that the server is started using SSH so you can capture the key and use it from a remote machine.

```bash
# Will bind to some open port, generate a key, and share it over stdout
distant server listen

# Prints out {port} {key}
# e.g.       1234   abcdef123456789
```

This was inspired by [mosh](https://mosh.org/), which follows a similar process by ssh'ing into a remote machine, spawning a mosh server (which forks itself to detach from the ssh session), and printing out a specific line `MOSH CONNECT {port} {key}` like below:

```
$ mosh-server


MOSH CONNECT 60001 iurF5lS6EVGE/ebYS4j6dQ

mosh-server (mosh 1.3.2) [build mosh-1.3.2]
Copyright 2012 Keith Winstein <mosh-devel@mit.edu>
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

[mosh-server detached, pid = 16165]
```

### Daemonizing the process on Unix

On Unix-based systems, I can use forking logic such as with the [fork crate](https://crates.io/crates/fork) to create a new process that won't terminate when the parent or associated shell tied to `sshd` terminates. The fork lets me share the generated key between the process that will print to the console and the daemonized process.

### How to daemonize the process on Windows?

On Windows, I'm struggling to figure out a way to either share a generated key with a created child process or communicate a generated key from the child process back to the original console. I've used the [creation flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` and `DETACHED_PROCESS` to spawn a child process in the background that won't terminate when the shell exits, but now the child process cannot communicate over stdin (to receive a key) or stdout (to report a key).

**Update:** even with the above detached process and new process group, it seems like creating this process from a shell connected to an OpenSSH server running on Windows still does not survive once the ssh session has been closed. Other than a Windows service, is there any way to create a background process that will survive being created during an ssh session?

### Windows code

```rust
use std::{
    os::windows::process::CommandExt,
    process::{Command, Stdio},
};

const DETACHED_PROCESS: u32 = 0x00000008;
const CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP: u32 = 0x00000200;
const CREATE_NO_WINDOW: u32 = 0x08000000;

// Spawn a child process that is not attached to this console or parent so it can keep
// running even after the parent process and even the associated shell have exited
//
// Inheriting stdin/stdout/stderr does nothing when we use DETACHED_PROCESS. Is there 
// a secure way to communicate with the child to either feed it a key or receive a key
// from it?
//
// Does CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP successfully daemonize without DETACHED_PROCESS? If so,
// can I use it to stay connected to the existing console?
let child = Command::new(program)
    .creation_flags(DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
    .args(args)
    .stdin(Stdio::inherit())
    .stdout(Stdio::inherit())
    .stderr(Stdio::inherit())
    .spawn()?;
```

Comment: Don't try to do things the Linux/POSIX way on Windows. There's generally a far superior solution on Windows, for literally *any* problem. You could use a (named) pipe here. Pipes on Windows, like all kernel objects, are securable objects (see [access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-control)).

Comment: Or, if the goal is to do something akin to a daemon on \*NIX platforms, you'll be pleasantly surprised to find out that Windows actually has a useful infrastructure for [services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services). That's what *systemd* had wanted to be when it grows up ([it never did](https://youtu.be/o_AIw9bGogo)).

Comment: @IInspectable, I'd looked into the Windows services route, but I wasn't sure if I could run more than one instance of the service and if I have the ability to alternate arguments to each service instance.

Separately, for named pipes, I was trying to figure out access controls and what is possible/needed there. The nice thing of stdin/out pipes is that the access is limited to the parent and child. With named pipes, I'd still want to restrict access to just between the parent and child to communicate the shared key. Is that a common or doable practice with these pipes? Is it even necessary?

Comment: Make it an anonymous pipe then. Without a name there's no way for anyone else to open a handle to it. As for service instances, I don't think there's a way for a service to have multiple instances running. However, a service can spawn any number of threads, and threads can impersonate clients. I'm guessing that's what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: @IInspectable actually, it looks like if I spawn the process using DETACHED_PROCESS and CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP from an ssh session connected to an OpenSSH server running on Windows, the process is still killed upon the ssh session being closed. Is the only way to keep a persistent process to use a windows service?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the child process at some point attaches to the parent's console (probably in Rust's Standard Library implementation). At that point, terminating one process tears down the respective other along the way. Probably something you could work around, if you need to, but you'll be using a lot more `windows` (or `windows-sys`) than the Standard Library. I'm still having a hard time understanding the specific issues that needs to be solved here. Expressing a problem in terms of the solution on a Linux-based system makes it really hard to actually see the problem.